# Saving captured getUserMedia video to file before POST to server

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am trying to write a small application that can record video in the browser and upload it to a server.

I have got the code below:

```
<html>
<body>

    <video id="video" playsinline autoplay></video>

    <script>
        function hasGetUserMedia() {
            return !!(navigator.mediaDevices &&
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
        }

        if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
            console.log("Good to go");
        } else {
            console.log('Not supported');
        }

        const constraints = {
          video: true,
          audio: true,
        };


        function start(){
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
            then((stream) => {video.srcObject = stream});
            var videoEl = document.getElementById('video');
            stream = videoEl.srcObject;
        }

        function stop(){
            var videoEl = document.getElementById('video');
            stream = videoEl.srcObject;
            tracks = stream.getTracks();
            tracks.forEach(function(track) {
               track.stop();
            });
            downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(tracks[0]));
            downloadLink.download = 'acetest.webm';

        }

    </script>

    <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
    <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>


</body>
```

I can see the video on the screen, but unsure how I can then capture that to a file to upload.

I have tried using `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(tracks[0]));` but this doesn't work. How can I save the video once the Stop button is pressed?